# Text affected by using txfonts package

Tags: fonts, symbols, packages

I am using a `\usepackage{txfonts}` because of this symbol `\multimapdotbothB` but the body text or fonts are affected. How can this be not to be affected?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

$\multimapdotbothB$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just load the single symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{txsyc}{m}{n}
%\SetSymbolFont{symbolsC}{bold}{U}{txsyc}{bx}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{ntxsyc}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbolsC}{bold}{U}{ntxsyc}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\multimapdotbothB}{\mathrel}{symbolsC}{24}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

$\multimapdotbothB$
\end{document}
```

I've loaded the `newtxmath` font, which is based on `txfonts`. I added the two commented lines in case you have an old TeX distribution.

Comment: Indeed much simpler than loading the full package and undoing most of what it's doing.