# How to load a single symbol for my LaTeX document

Tags: symbols, txfonts

I simply want to use the `\multimapboth` symbol, which belongs to the `\txfonts` package; however I don't want to install this package, as it changes some formatting on my document... How can I do this? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I'm looking for something like the answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70040/text-affected-by-using-txfonts-package) question, just don't know how can I find more details about my symbol...

Comment: take a look at this:  [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130569/sharp-or-angled-v-in-math-mode-varv/130619#130619, for importing from `txfonts`

Comment: I found everything I need here: http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/symbols/ Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these to your preamble.

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{txsyc}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbolsC}{bold}{U}{txsyc}{bx}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{txsyc}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\multimapboth}{\mathrel}{symbolsC}{"13}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{txfonts}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{txsyc}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbolsC}{bold}{U}{txsyc}{bx}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{txsyc}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\multimapboth}{\mathrel}{symbolsC}{"13}
\begin{document}
  $\multimapboth$
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do we know what to do?

Look in to the `txfonts.sty` for the definition of `\multimapboth`. It is something like

```
 \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\multimapboth}{\mathrel}{symbolsC}{"13}
```

Now you need the definition of `symbolsC`. Look for it in the same file.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Math Symbols C %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{txsyc}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbolsC}{bold}{U}{txsyc}{bx}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{txsyc}{m}{n}
```

Put both together and you are good to go.